# MiniMagick Ruby cropping external images returns the image too small

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minimagick

I am running the following code and a I am getting an unexpected output for external images.

```
require "mini_magick"
image = MiniMagick::Image.open('https://s3.amazonaws.com/dropsitecms/32a0f5e44c6ab32db614e1dbe6e773900708de5f.demo.cloudvent.net/raw/uploads/versions/404-circle-cf2d9a11b44d04de64d68843dd278140---%280-76-266-114-350-150%29---.png')

image.crop "260x112!+0+0"
image.write 'image.jpg'
system("open image.jpg")
```

Starting with this base image:

[image]

It returns this result which is far too small:

[image: untitled-4]

I get the expected result when I start with a local copy of the base image:

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Downloading the file to a tmp file and then cropping it would work but hoping to have a fix in minimagick for this.

Comment: Can you post what would be the expected result? I see the same result whether is a local copy or fetching from the URL.

Comment: Sure will do that now

Comment: Interesting. I get the same result (the small one), both when fetching from the URL and when using the downloaded file.

Comment: Interesting, Mine is working for the local file. I don't work with ruby all that much but is seems like something is not waiting.

Comment: Which mini_magick version are you using? Also, which ImageMagick version do you have installed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59479/discussion-between-nobita-and-georgephillips).

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter settings are wrong, change width/height this,then it will work, just have a try :

```
require "mini_magick"
image = MiniMagick::Image.open('aa.png')

image.crop "100x200!+0+0"
image.write 'image.png'
```

Comment: Could you give me a reference for: p "*"*20

Comment: p is an abbreviation for print

Comment: The only difference in the code I see is that you are loading the image from a local file system and you changed the width and height. I need it to take in an external url and the width and height are variable.